# How to fire a disabled WooCommerce New Order notification?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the admin or store owner emails disabled but would like to programmatically fire the action so that once a function runs using AJAX to finalize an order I can send the email as intended, but only after an AJAX function that is fired on the return of the reciept page after payment.

The flow is as follows currently:
`Add to Cart -> Cart -> Checkout -> Reciept Page (disabled new order email here) -> Redirect to Payment -> Payment -> Redirect to final Reciept Page (send the disabled new order notification here).`

I'm trying to use the following to send the disabled new order email:

`// Get the WC_Email_New_Order object
$email_new_order = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order'];
// Sending the new Order email notification for an $order_id (order ID)
$email_new_order->trigger( $order->get_id() );`

but the email is never sent, I assume because its disabled under WC > Settings > Email > New Order - but is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering my own question, using the **woocommerce_email_enabled_new_order** filter and setting it to *true* prior to triggering the email, example:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_enabled_new_order', function($enabled, $order) {
      return true;
}, 10, 2 );`